# Trying to generate 2 vectors with 10 random numbers between 0-10

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, methods

I'm new here and I'm looking for help with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int o;
    Vector v1 = new Vector();
    Vector v2 = new Vector();
    o = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Welcome!\n"
            + "\n"
            + "Please select an Option: \n"
            + "1. Generate vectors A and B \n"
            + "2. Show vector's sum between elements \n"
            + "3. Sum both vectors \n"));
    switch (o) {

        case 1:
            class v1 () {
            int length = 10;
            int[] series = new int[length];
            for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            series[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, series[i]);
        }
            class v2 () {
            int length = 10;
            int[] series = new int[length];
            for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            series[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, series[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

}

The thing is, I'm only allowed to use methods, classes, arrays and objects. Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What's not working, though? Is the logic not correct? (Also, Java is basically all "methods, classes, arrays, and objects")

Comment: Is this [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) ?

Comment: You are declaring Vector objects incorrectly (and then not even using them).  And your class structure in your switch statements is incorrect.

Comment: @user Sorry for the tags... I'm new to this forum.... :(

Comment: @Abra this is an exercise to train myself that i found in a book.

Comment: @WJS Thanks for the feedback! I'm gonna do my best to get it right!

Answer (score 1):

Declare the Vectors as follows:

```
Vector<Integer> v1 = new Vector<>();
```

To add a value

```
v1.add(1);
```

To get a value

```
int b = v1.get(0); // b == 1
```

To print a vector

```
System.out.println(v1);
```

For more information see [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Vector.html).  And since you have other significant syntax errors in your code check out [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for help.

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest way. [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-)

PS : dont use Vector even you are working withmulti threads.

```
 List<Integer> ints = new java.util.Random()
                .ints(10, 0, 10)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
```